# Getting base URL in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to get the base URL for the project in Yii 2 but it doesn't seem to work. According to [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22159-getbaseurl-returns-empty/page__view__findpost__p__109510) you used to be able to do:

```
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);
```

In Yii 1, but it seems that [that method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#getBaseUrl()-detail) in Yii 2 no longer accepts a parameter?

I've tried doing it without true, such as:

```
Yii::$app->getBaseUrl();
```

But it just returns empty.

How can you do this in Yii 2?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html

Comment: try Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To get base URL of application you should use [`yii\helpers\Url::base()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#base()-detail) method:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

Url::base();         // /myapp
Url::base(true);     // http(s)://example.com/myapp - depending on current schema
Url::base('https');  // https://example.com/myapp
Url::base('http');   // http://example.com/myapp
Url::base('');       // //example.com/myapp
```

[`Url::home()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#home()-detail) **should NOT be used in this case**. [`Application::$homeUrl`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-application#$homeUrl-detail) uses base URL by default, but it could be easily changed (for example to `https://example.com/myapp/home`) so you should not rely on assumption that it will always return base URL. If there is a special `Url::base()` method to get base URL, then use it.

Answer (score 34):

My guess is that you need to look at aliases.

Using aliases would be like:

```
Yii::getAlias('@web');
```

You can also always rely on one of these two:

```
Yii::$app->homeUrl;

Url::base();
```

Comment: `Url` btw is from `yii\helpers\Url`

Comment: I tried `Url::home(true)` and `Url::base(true)` and they both pretty much return the same thing, except `Url::home(true)` includes an ending `/`. Is there any difference other than that?

Comment: Anyone know the difference? Can provide an example?

Comment: @Brett Yii Framework is totally open and docummented on github, you should check https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseUrl.php#L293 and compare  functions, Url:home relies on URI:scheme to return URL if defined otherwise it will return Yii::$app->getHomeUrl(); in the otherway URL:base is the same when scheme = true but, when scheme is false the url is given by $url = Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl(); I strongly suggest not to be afraid to check out yii code by yourself, it is amazingly well docummented

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer to include `Url::base(true)` instead as that's probably the one I will use.

Answer (score 11):

To get base URL Yii2 using:

```
Url::home(true)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `Url::home()` does not always return base URL. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546628/5812455).

Answer (score 7):

Use it like this:

```
Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl()
```

More information on base, canonical, home URLs: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-url.html

Comment: Anytime you see `get` as the function base name, it is a `getter` function. Meaning you can just do: `Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl`. The functions are ugly and looks like you don't understand the point of getter functions.

Comment: @WadeShuler Getters are only syntax sugar with some performance implications - using methods is actually preferred.  In framework core they're used almost every time.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$baseUrl = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/']);
```

Answer (score 3):

may be you are looking for this

```
Yii::$app->homeUrl
```

you can also use this

```
Url::base().
```

or this

`Url::home();`

Answer (score 2):

You can reach your base URL by this:

```
Yii::$app->request->baseUrl
```

Answer (score 2):

I searched for a solution how we can do like in codeigniter, routing like 
e.g.

```
base_url()
base_url('profile')
base_url('view/12')
```

## Only way we can do that in Yii2

```
<?=Url::toRoute('/profile') ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code. It should work. It will return base URL name

use yii\helpers\Url;

Url::home('http') // http://HostName/
OR
Url::home('https') // https://HostName/

Answer (score -1):

In yii 1 this code return the hostname

```
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);
```

In yii2 the following

```
Yii::$app->getBaseUrl();
```

not exists as method of Yii::$app and it triggers an error with message

```
Calling unknown method: yii\web\Application::getBaseUrl()
```

You could use Request class that encapsulates the $_SERVER

```
Yii::$app->request->hostInfo
```